# Two object arguments in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to convert

```
console.log({
  a: 'a'
}, {
  b: 'b'
});
```

into CoffeeScript. The only way I found is

```
console.log
  a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
```

It seems bizarre that `a: 'a'` and `b: 'b'` are not indented the same when they are essentially symetric in this situation.

Comment: Just because you can leave off braces/parens in coffeescript, it doesn't mean you should.  This is probably one of the "shouldn't" cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or you could use braces, which do work in CS:

```
console.log {a:'a'}, {b:'b'}
```

Comment: Right, braces and parentheses are (usually) optional but there's no reason for contortions to avoid them.

Answer (score 31):

Put the comma one in a separated line, **one indentation level less than** the hash/object, so it's treated as part of the function invocation.

```
console.log
   a: 'a'
, # indentation level matters!
   b: 'b'
```

this will not work because the indentation level is the same as hash, so it's treated as part of the hash.

```
console.log
   a: 'a'
   ,
   b: 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you think about the parsing rules,

```
a: 'a',
b: 'b'
```

actually means

```
{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

Since this isn't the behaviour you want, you need to tell the parser that the line with `b:` is another object. Indenting will do that for you. Now this wasn't really a question, but I hope it helps you understand why to do it the way you described. It is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ coffee -bce 'console.log(a: "a"; b: "b")'
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.2.1-pre

console.log({
  a: "a"
}, {
  b: "b"
});
```